# excel 2013 convert column data format from 'yyyymmdd hhmm' to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, vba

How can i convert in excel 2013 column data format from 'yyyymmdd hhmm' to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: This might not be that simple. Might as well provide an actual sample date?

Comment: What is the data type here? Text? All the number formats in the world won't help if your data is text. Screenshot or sample file would help.

Answer (score 1):

Click on any cell in the column and run this macro:

```
Sub DateFormat()
    With ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, click on the top of the column to select all of the cells within that column, then right click on a random cell within that column and click 'Format Cells', from here a box will show up.

The box will have all different format rules, and by default it should be on the 'Number' tab within the box, from here select 'Date' and then you will be able to select the appropriate type of date format from here that you wish to have.

For your case you should see one corresponding to your yyyy-mm--dd format

Comment: True, my mistake, I didn't read the tags, he didn't state in the question nor the description that it had to be VBA.

At least my answer provides an alternate way of solving the issue, and of course is far more simpler.

Comment: Simpler *if* the data is numeric *and* if this is not part of a broader VBA-based application :)

Answer (score -1):

If it is text-to-text: `=LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&MID(A1,7,2)` (split and rejoin the string)
If it is date-to-text: `=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")` 
If it is text-to-date, make a date with: `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))` (split the string and give the parts to the DATE function) ...
... to show date type cells in a different format, use methods above (if you don't have yyyy-mm-dd in your "Date" options, you can type it in under "Custom")

Comment: @David-zemens You are right - but tagging often seems a little off and why use a sledgehammer to crack a nut? Btw - why only downvote me, not the other non-VBA "Format cells" option?!

Comment: *why use a sledgehammer* I'd argue that VBA is not a sledgehammer; filling the worksheet with an extra helper column and formulas *is*. But probably best to just *not answer* poor questions like this: it shows no research effort, OP has provided no code of his/her own, and not even an example of the current data, nor has responded to any of the inquiries asking for more detail. I did downvote the other answer, although as far as sledgehammers are concerned, that one may actually be superior -- of course since the OP has not indicated what sort of data he actually has, it is impossible to say.